# How is earphone use regulated in WSOP?

Tags: rules, wsop

I was recently watching a WSOP event on YouTube and noticed that a few players were wearing earphones.

Knowing that hole cards are displayed to television viewers, couldn't a player theoretically have someone watching the game on screen feed him his opponents cards through whatever device he is supposed to be listening to music through? I'm sure this is regulated somehow, but how do they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [WSOP 2016 rulebook](https://www.wsop.com/2016/WSOP%202016%20Live%20Action%20Rules.pdf) :

- 25. All cell phones and other voice-enabled and “ringing” devices are allowed as long as it does not impede the progress of the game.

> [...] but shall not be permitted to text/email any other participant at the table.

- 24. Participants are allowed to use approved electronic devices, iPods, MP3 and other music participants or noise reduction headsets during Live Action play.

> [...] cannot be used to collude, cheat, or communicate with another participant during a hand.

[PokerNews](https://www.pokernews.com/news/2016/04/the-world-series-of-poker-announces-enhancements-24652.htm) says that **Web Streaming Changes** include *Live coverage [...] on a 30-minute delay for hold'em and Omaha where hole cards will be displayed*

Live streaming of the final table won't make it different as earphones won't be allowed at that time.

> Therefore, it seems **nearly impossible** that players involved in a hand can gather some information from insiders/outsiders.

Comment: `Live coverage [...] on a 30-minute delay `  and if you try to tank for anywhere near 30 minutes the clock will be called on you!

Comment: IMHO, no way this can ever happen though ^^ According to [WSOP rules - calling the clock](https://www.wsop.com/2017/Rule%2520Change%2520-%2520Calling%2520the%2520Clock.pdf) `participants were permitted to call the clock after a “reasonable amount of time” had passed, and 2 minutes was defined as the minimum reasonable amount of time. **That two-minute guideline has been removed.** Participants may now call the clock at any point if they feel a participant at the table is taking longer than is reasonable for the game situation.`

Comment: SE links do not like spaces in URL :/ ( https://www.wsop.com/2017/Rule Change - Calling the Clock.pdf )

Answer (score 2):

The audience does not get a real time feed.   It is delayed.